# ERROR: record type has not been registered

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting `ERROR: record type has not been registered` with the following postgresql script, even though I have registered the t as being record. I don't understand what is wrong with this code. Could somebody help me please?

```
do $$
declare
t record;
begin
create or replace view v_big_hitters as
with scale as (
    select /*+ materialize */ low, high from (
        select lag(v) over (order by v) low, v high from (
            select * from unnest(ARRAY[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100])
        ) v
    ) v where low is not null
),
match_count as (
    select /*+ materialize */ cn.nol_no, count(m.origin_id) nb_match
    from cases c
    join case_match cm on cm.case_id = c.id
    join match m on m.id = cm.match_id
    join case_nol cn on cn.case_id = c.id
    group by cn.nol_no
),
nol_by_bucket as (
    select t.*, case when lag(bucket_low) over (order by rn)=bucket_low then null else 'x' end first_in_bucket from (
        select
            round(t.running_match/t.overall_match*100,2) perct, (select COALESCE(min(low),100) from scale where t.running_match/t.overall_match*100<high) bucket_low
        from (
            select
                nol_no, nb_match,
                sum(nb_match) over (partition by null) overall_match,
                sum(nb_match) over (order by nb_match desc, nol_no ) running_match,
                row_number() over (order by nb_match desc, nol_no) rn
            from match_count
        ) t
    ) t
    order by nb_match desc ,nol_no
)
select
    high as distribution,
    running_nol-nvl(lag(running_nol) over (order by high),0) count_of_nol,
    running_nol cumulative_count_of_nol,
    running_match-nvl(lag(running_match) over (order by high),0) count_of_match,
    running_match cumulative_count_of_match
from (
    select
        s.high, COALESCE(max(nbb.running_match) over (order by s.high),0) running_match, COALESCE(max(nbb.rn) over (order by s.high),0) running_nol
    from
        scale s
        left join (select * from nol_by_bucket where first_in_bucket='x' and bucket_low>0) nbb on (s.high=nbb.bucket_low)
) s
order by high;
end;
$$
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE**
Based on the comments I have updated the code:

```
create or replace view v_big_hitters as
with scale as (
    select /*+ materialize */ low, high from (
        select lag(v) over (order by v) low, v high from (
            select * from unnest(ARRAY[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100])
        ) as x(v)
    ) v where low is not null
),
match_count as (
    select /*+ materialize */ cn.nol_no, count(m.origin_id) nb_match
    from cases c
    join case_match cm on cm.case_id = c.id
    join match m on m.id = cm.match_id
    join case_nol cn on cn.case_id = c.id
    group by cn.nol_no
),
nol_by_bucket as (
    select t.*, case when lag(bucket_low) over (order by rn--this is where the error occurs)=bucket_low then null else 'x' end as first_in_bucket from (
        select
            round(t.running_match/t.overall_match*100,2) perct, (select COALESCE(min(low),100) from scale where t.running_match/t.overall_match*100<high) bucket_low
        from (
            select
                nol_no, nb_match,
                sum(nb_match) over (partition by null) overall_match,
                sum(nb_match) over (order by nb_match desc, nol_no ) running_match,
                row_number() over (order by nb_match desc, nol_no) rn
            from match_count order by nb_match desc ,nol_no
        ) t
    ) t
)
select
    high as distribution,
    running_nol-nvl(lag(running_nol) over (order by high),0) count_of_nol,
    running_nol cumulative_count_of_nol,
    running_match-nvl(lag(running_match) over (order by high),0) count_of_match,
    running_match cumulative_count_of_match
from (
    select
        s.high, COALESCE(max(nbb.running_match) over (order by s.high),0) running_match, COALESCE(max(nbb.rn) over (order by s.high),0) running_nol
    from
        scale s
        left join (select * from nol_by_bucket where first_in_bucket='x' and bucket_low>0) nbb on (s.high=nbb.bucket_low)
) s
order by high;
```

Now I am getting `ERROR: column "rn" does not exist`

Comment: The `do` block makes no sense to me, what are you trying to achieve with that?  And Postgres has no `/*+ materialize */` hint

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: I would suspect the fact that `v` is a column alias and a table alias a the same time. Try `) as x(v)` in the first derived table so that `v` only refers to a column alias (instead of just `) v`)